# How can I run a cronjob on multiple nodes sequentially in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob, nodeselector

I have two different types of worker nodes, ones that do data preparation and nodes that do machine learning.
I want to run a Cronjob that runs one process on a preparation node, then (only when finished) a second process on an ML node.
How can I do this in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to run a Cronjob that runs one process on a preparation node, then (only when finished) a second process on an ML node.

A CronJob is only one Pod.

What you want to do here is a *Workflow* or *Pipeline* consisting of two pods, executed on different nodes.

This can be done with e.g. [Argo Workflow](https://argoproj.github.io/argo/) or [Kubeflow Pipelines](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/pipelines/overview/pipelines-overview/) or maybe [Tekton Pipeline](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline).